# Windows Store UWP: ApplicationContentUriRule with 'all' or 'allowForWebOnly' are not allowed with capabilties removableStorage

Tags: javascript, uwp

The Application cannot include an ApplicationContentUriRule with 'all' or 'allowForWebOnly' WindowsRuntimeAccess while any of the following capabilities are enabled: enterpriseAuthentication, sharedUserCertificates, musicLibrary, picturesLibrary, videosLibrary, removableStorage, documentLibrary, internetClientServer, privateNetworkClientServer.

Comment: I found some similar [descriptions](https://github.com/apache/cordova-windows/blob/master/cordova-windows10.md#remote-access-and-capabilities), and do you use cordova app?